# What does "comma bar" mean?

Tags: apl

Please pardon my ignorance.  I'm translating some APL to another format, and can't find anywhere what the function/meaning of a "comma bar" is.  Not sure if this will come through, but it looks like this "⍪", and is encoded by U+236A.

It appears to combine 2 matrices, but while I've found a few mentions of the symbol itself, Google has not yet been able to tell me what it does.

For extra gratitude, please point me to a source where I can find information about what all the other symbols do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dyadic form of [comma-bar](http://www.microapl.co.uk/apl_help/ch_020_020_490.htm) is called a [first-axis catenate](http://www.microapl.com/apl_help/ch_020_020_500.htm).

> With matrices and other multi-dimensional arrays, catenate expects the dimension at which the join is made to be specified. (See [], 'axis'.) If no dimension is specified, the last dimension is assumed. ⍪ (comma-bar) behaves in exactly the same manner as , except that the default dimension is the first. Again, if an axis is specified ⍪ will use that axis.

This microapl site has a good [reference of basic symbols](http://www.microapl.co.uk/apl_help/ch_020_020.htm) as well.

Search that site and wikipedia and you should have enough to go on. See the comments below for an implementation specific monadic version.

Comment: In some implementations, monadic comma-bar is the "table" function which turns a vector of length N into an N-by-1 matrix.  Example: `⍪'ABC' ←→ 3 1⍴'ABC'`.

Comment: That's a good point, I should have mentioned that I described the dyadic.